# How replace on InMemory DB .net?

Tags: c#, .net, database, unit-testing, in-memory-database

For integration tests, I want to replace the connection from the real database with the inmemory database. But all the same, in tests, the connection is with a real database.

This two options for replacing with inmemory DB:

```
public class TestWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
        : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup: class
    {
                protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
                {
                    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<TownContext>));
                        services.RemoveAll(typeof(TownContext));
                        services.RemoveAll(typeof(IServiceCollection));
                        services.AddDbContext<TownContext>(options => { 
                             options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"); });
        
                        services.RemoveAll(typeof(IServiceProvider));
                        services.AddSingleton((serviceProvider) =>
                        {
                            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TownContext> 
                            ().UseInMemoryDatabase("orders");
                            return optionsBuilder.Options;
                        });
                    });   
                //... 
                }
     //... 
     }
```

More can be seen on github https://github.com/OlgerdDragon/WebApiTestGit.git File TestWebApplicationFactory.cs

Please help me how to replace the database correctly?

Comment: What are exactly the two options? What is not working correctly in the solution(s) you propose?

Comment: one: 
"  services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<TownContext>)); 
...
"
two:
"
ervices.RemoveAll(typeof(IServiceProvider));
...
"

As I wrote above, the real database is not replaced by inmemory.